# Copying a string and changing its value doesn't change the original value

Tags: c#, button, textbox

```
public string gametext;

public Gameplay()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    gametext = tbGameplayMessage.Text;
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gametext += "Write textbox \r\n";
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gametext += "Write textbox \r\n";
}
```

That is my code what I'm trying to do is update the TextBox everytime I click button, and write more lines when clicking button2.
My textbox already has the multiline enabled.
When I run my code nothing happens to textbox :(

Comment: in your button click event, do this `tbGameplayMessage.Text = gametext;`  .

Comment: Please note that you only assign the value to variable `gametext`, rather than 
 `tbGameplayMessage.Text`.

Comment: @Li-JyuGao it worked, thanks, but can you explain me a little more why isn't working like I wrote it

Comment: So, if i wanted to assign the value from my variable to the TextBox, how can I do that. Sorry just starting coding since last 2 months @KyleWang

Comment: @Slad3X   Textbox's property `Text`'s value is always assigned by a new string value. Your variable `gametext` won't change the `Text` if `gametext`'s value changes. Until you manually assign value to `Text`.

Comment: @Slad3X `gametext` and `tbGameplayMessage.Text` can be seen as two independent variables. So you need to assign a value to "tbGameplayMessage.Text" manually. Their values are not "synchronized".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to your problem is to just update the `Text` property directly:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbGameplayMessage.Text+= "Write textbox \r\n";
}
```

So let's take a look at what's happening.

`Text` is a `string` *property*:

```
tbGameplayMessage.Text
```

`string` is a [*reference type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), we know if we copy a reference we have 2 variables pointing to the same location in memory.

Let's see this in action:

```
// create a string
var a = "test1";
// copy a to b
var b = a;

// this is just a way of getting our strings position in memory 
fixed (char* pa = a,pb = b)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"a : {a} @ {(uint)pa}"); 
   Console.WriteLine($"b : {b} @ {(uint)pb}");
}
```

**Output**

```
a : test1 @ 51748
b : test1 @ 51748
```

As you can see, `a` and `b` are pointing to the same *memory location* `51748`. Ok so far so good

But watch what happens when we assign a new string (`"test2"`) to `a`

```
a = "test2";

fixed (char* pa = a, pb = b)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"a : {a} @ {(uint)pa}");
   Console.WriteLine($"b : {b} @ {(uint)pb}");
}
```

Output

```
a : test2 @ 51876
b : test1 @ 51748
```

Notice `b` still contains the original `string` `test1` and pointing to the same *location*, yet `a` has taken our new `string`, and is pointing to a different *location*.

This is because `string` is a reference type and your variables are only holding a pointer (post-it-note) to the location of the actual memory.

When you assign another reference to a variable, you are giving it a new location to point to in memory

This is the very reason why you can't assign your  `tbGameplayMessage.Text` to `gametext` and expect `tbGameplayMessage.Text` change when you change `gametext`

```
gametext = tbGameplayMessage.Text;
```

The above is copying the *reference* to the string held in `Text`.

When you give `gametext` a new *reference*, `Text` still has the old *reference* (it doesn't change).

Let's see this in action a little better:

```
var a = "test";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   a += i;

   fixed (char* pa = a)
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"a : {a} @ {(uint) pa}");
   }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a : test10 @ 67684
a : test101 @ 67812
a : test1012 @ 67940
a : test10123 @ 68068
a : test101234 @ 68196
```

Every time we touch the string, it points to a different location.

---

Now for a bonus fact, if we assign `"test1"` back to `a` look what happens:

```
a = "test1";

fixed (char* pa = a, pb = b)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"a : {a} @ {(uint)pa}");
   Console.WriteLine($"b : {b} @ {(uint)pb}");
}
```

**Output**

```
a : test1 @ 51748
b : test1 @ 51748
```

Magically it points to the original *location* again.. This is because *strings* are *interned*. String interning refers to having a single copy of each unique string in an string intern pool, which is looked up via a hash table. this is basically a memory saving feature that is done under-the-hood, and totally irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :D 
Now I have a better understanding